# How to use captured lifetime token in function parameter

Tags: function, generics, rust, macros, lifetime

Here is the code:

```rust
struct A<'a, 'b> {
    s1: &'a str,
    s2: &'b str,
}

struct B<'a> {
    s3: &'a str,
}

macro_rules! gen_fn {
    ( $name:ident, $param:ty, < $($gen:tt),+ > ) => {
        fn $name< $($gen),+ >(param: $param< $($gen),+ >) {
            todo!()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    gen_fn!( op_a, A, <'a, 'b>);
    gen_fn!( op_b, B, <'a> );
}
```

However this code can't compile because Rust consider `$param` as a single argument, and `$gen` is another argument, so it expect token `,` or `)`.

When I try to expand the macro, the code is generated as I expect:

```rust
fn op_a<'a, 'b>(param: A<'a, 'b>) {
    $crate::panicking::panic("not yet implemented")
}
fn op_b<'a>(param: B<'a>) {
    $crate::panicking::panic("not yet implemented")
}
```

Am I doing wrong or it is just unsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ident` instead of `ty`, but only if you're not using paths (`a::b`):

```rust
macro_rules! gen_fn {
    ( $name:ident, $param:ident, < $($gen:tt),+ > ) => {
        fn $name< $($gen),+ >(param: $param< $($gen),+ >) {
            todo!()
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using paths, you can use a repeated `ident`:

```rust
macro_rules! gen_fn {
    ( $name:ident, $($param:ident)::+, < $($gen:tt),+ > ) => {
        fn $name< $($gen),+ >(param: $($param)::+< $($gen),+ >) {
            todo!()
        }
    }
}
```